# Node MongoDB memory leak issue

Tags: node.js, mongodb, memory-leaks

I'm writing a webservice using **Node.js**.

This webservice makes calls to a MongoDB and MSSQL.

For MSSQL i've use npm mssql library, for mongo i use the native npm **mongodb** library.
I use **Q** as my promise library.

I've a **memory leak issue** running a find over a **MongoDB** collection. I simply need to get elements from a connection. And eventually update the status of elements i get.
See my sample code below.

```js
var Q = require('q');
var connection = require('..\connection.js'); //the connection module open a connection that can be used with pools.

function list(req, res) {
    return Q.Promise(function(resolve, reject, notify) {
      var collection = null;
      var result = [];
      var cursor = null;
      Q.fcall(function(){}).then(function() {
        collection = connection.collection(collectionName);
      })
      .then(function() {
        cursor = collection.find({ fieldstatus : 0 });
        return Q.Promise(function(resolve, reject, notify) {
          Q.allSettled(cursor.each(function(err, item){
            return Q.fcall(function(){
              try {
                if(item != null) {
                  result.push({
                    field1 : item.field1,
                    field2 : item.field2,
                    fieldstatus : item.fieldstatus
                  });
                  collection.update({_id: item._id}, {$set: {fieldstatus : 1}});
                }
                resolve(result);
              } catch (err){
                reject(err);
              }
            })
            .fin(function() {
              cursor.close();
            });
          }));
        });
      })
      .then(function(ret) {
        resolve(ret);
      })
      .fail(function(err) {
        reject([ err.toString() ]);
      })
      .fin(function() {
        result = null;
        cursor = null;
        collection = null;
      });
    })
    .fail(function(err) {
      throw([ err.toString() ]);
    });
  }
}
```

## UPDATED : Answer 1

The code below seems to works without leak issuess.

```
var Q = require('q');
var connection = require('..\connection.js'); //the connection module open a connection that can be used with pools.

function list(req, res) {
    return Q.Promise(function(resolve, reject, notify) {
      var collection = null;
      var result = [];
      var cursor = null;
      Q.fcall(function(){}).then(function() {
        collection = connection.collection(collectionName);
      })
      .then(function() {
        return Q.npost(
          collection,
          "find",
          [ 
            { fieldstatus : 0 }
          ]
        ).then(function(ret){
          return Q.npost(ret, "toArray").then(function(item){
            return item;
          });
        })
        .then(function(ret){
          var result = [];
          ret.forEach(function (item) {
            result.push({
              field1 : item.field1,
              field2 : item.field2,
              fieldstatus : item.fieldstatus
            });
            collection.update({_id: item._id}, {$set: {fieldstatus : 1}});
          });
          return result;
        })
      })
      .then(function(ret) {
        resolve(ret);
      })
      .fail(function(err) {
        reject([ err.toString() ]);
      })
      .fin(function() {
        collection = null;
      });
    })
    .fail(function(err) {
      throw([ err.toString() ]);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: how do you know that you have a memory leak?

Comment: After making many (almost 5000 rpm) calls to this api, memory grows little by little.
Other API routes (and functions) doesn't give me this problem.